# How to install hive on hadoop in CentOS?

Tags: hadoop, installation, hive, centos

I have configured the hadoop2.7.3 on centos 6.8 and running fine.

Need some help regarding the installation of HIVE on top of Hadoop CentOS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a quickstart for an impatient:

Download and install Hive to the same directory, where you have installed Hadoop (e.g. if Hadoop is in /opt/hadoop, Hive should be in /opt/hive):

```
wget http://apache.rediris.es/hive/hive-2.1.0/apache-hive-2.1.0-bin.tar.gz
tar -xvf apache-hive-2.1.0-bin.tar.gz 
mv apache-hive-2.1.0-bin hive
cd hive
```

Generate derby metastore

```
bin/schematool  -dbType derby -initSchema
```

Launch Hive:

```
bin/hive
```

Hive documentation really helps:                            https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/GettingStarted

Comment: ERROR XBM0H: Directory /opt/hive/metastore_db cannot be created - 
getting this error